# Counter on toolbar cart icon

Tags: android, shopping-cart, android-toolbar

I am trying to add a counter on cart icon

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            menu.clear();
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            RelativeLayout badge =(RelativeLayout)menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart).getActionView();
            ui_hot = (TextView) badge.findViewById(R.id.count);
        }
 return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

But i get the following message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.RelativeLayout.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Following is the Xml menu file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart"
        android:title="Test Counter Action"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/cart_update_count"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Please add XML file of menu

Answer (score -3):

this May help you out`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
      <Textview
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/myTextview"
         android:background="#000000" /> </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`**
```

Comment: Please read the question again. Like your previous answer, this too, has no relevance to the question asked.

Comment: This is not a solution at all. The answer it way too vague.